# HMTimerTrigger for selected days using NSCalendar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, homekit

I am working on Homekit based application, In That Homekit supports Triggers which fires on a specific date and it can be scheduled to fire repetitively by minutes, hour, days, week and month.

I want to schedule the Trigger to fire on specific days which is selected by user like mon,tue,wed,thu only or weekends (sat, sun).

I have set the **recurrence** using `NSDateComponents` but not able to set the repeat it for specific days.

Is there any way to schedule it by `recurrenceCalendar` object?
`HMTimerTrigger`'s method has this object which can be passed as parameter.

```
    HMTimerTrigger *newTrigger = [[HMTimerTrigger alloc] initWithName:@"Morning Schedule"
                                                         fireDate:self.fireDate
                                                         timeZone:nil
                                                       recurrence:recurranceComp
                                               recurrenceCalendar:nil];
```

Comment: have you had any luck with this topic?

Comment: No, Seems there is no way to do that. Apple didn't provided any api for that. I have done much r&d on that, but didn't find any workaround. I think I should close the tread.

Comment: I have filed a feature enhancement request with Apple. You should as well.

Comment: I think leaving the thread open is a good idea. Others looking for the answer will find this.